# Where should my project include new.h from? (Visual Studio and/or SDK corruption or version incompatibility?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I have a project that started as a Visual Studio 2005 project, and is now a Visual Studio 2019 project. It is built using the 142 Platform Toolset on Windows 10, but for deployment on Windows 8.1 and later. So it selects the Windows 8.1 SDK, and sets WINVER, _WIN32_WINNT and _WIN32_WINDOWS all to 0x0603.

It's an MFC project, so `stdafx.h` is virtually everywhere. That includes `afxwin.h`, which in turn includes `afx.h` and that includes `new.h`. It all builds fine on my desktop development machine with version 16.4.3 of Visual Studio 2019 Community.

I have just tried building the project on a laptop just after upgrading to "the latest" Visual Studio version (16.6.2). It fails to build because it cannot find `new.h`. As far as I can tell, `new.h` should be part of the SDK. But `new.h` is not in the Windows 8.1 SDK (or at least: not mine).

But what really confuses me is that when I track down `new.h` in my successful build, also configured to use the Windows 8.1 SDK, it finds `new.h` in the Windows 10 SDK.

I'm not clear if I have (a) a bad project (b) 1 or more bad Visual Studio installations (c) 1 or more bad SDK installations. Where should I expect to find `new.h` under such circumstances, and does that shine any light on which of a, b or c I'm experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case (d): you are missing the Windows SDK 8.1 installation on the laptop. That needs to be done separately from the VS install. From the Visual Studio 2019 v16.0 Release Notes - [Deprecations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.0#-deprecations):

> *The Windows 8.1 SDK is no longer available in the Visual Studio installer. Please upgrade your C++ projects to the latest Windows 10 SDK*. ***If you have a hard dependency on 8.1***, *you can download it from the [Windows SDK archive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive)*.

---

[ *EDIT* ] Targeting the Windows SDK 8.1 does *not* remove all references to the Windows 10 SDK, which is still required and used. For example, the include path for a C++ MFC project using the v142 toolset and the v8.1 SDK is set by default to the following on my machine.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\atlmfc\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\VC\Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\Include\um
```

Comment: Not the case for my laptop - the SDK was installed yesterday. Also, if I use Visual Studio command line, and type `echo %INCLUDE%`, I get a list similar to that on both machines. I believe using the Windows 10 SDK ucrt as the source is correct... and it is present in **both** systems. Can't see why it would not find it :-(

Comment: @omatai In the IDE, if you go to Project Properties / Configuration Properties / VC++ Directories / Include Directories and click Edit as if pretending to change them, do you see the same directories listed under Evaluated Value?

Comment: Unsure. I uninstalled VS 2019, then reinstalled... and now it refuses to load my project at all :-( I cannot see any way to install the same specific VS 2019 Community version on my desktop machine - only Enterprise or Professional editions :-( Working on it...

Comment: I suspect it is all related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442907/install-previous-version-of-visual-studio-community

Comment: And because the latest version of VS Community seems thoroughly broken, I cannot answer your question at all - I cannot load projects at all to view their properties :-(

Comment: If that's the only version of VS on that machine, maybe try the [InstallCleanup tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Your answer was not 100%... but it provided the impetus to discover that my VS 2019 installation was indeed corrupt... even though after cleanup, the corruption persisted... before mysteriously disappearing when I tried to log what was happening. Bizarre.

Comment: @omatai Glad it helped. And, yes, I know first hand that VS installs are sometimes *unique* experiences ;-)