# Install previous version of Visual Studio Community

Tags: visual-studio

Judging by [this discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/601456/how-can-i-downgrade-to-the-prior-version-of-vs-201.html), a lot of people really want/need the ability to either roll back a Visual Studio Community 2019 upgrade, or preferably, be able to install a specific release of it.

Is there any bypass/shortcut/similar method to achieve this? It appears Microsoft stubbornly refuse to support it.

For the record, the upgrade of MS Visual Studio Community 2019 from whichever version I downloaded on March 20 to the latest (16.6.2) at first broke my project builds, and when I uninstalled and reinstalled, it refused to load any project at all. Similar results were seen late yesterday on a colleague's laptop before he took today off :-(

Providing an "upgrade" button without a very clear warning about the impossibility of going backwards is not going to win Microsoft any friends...

Answer (score 2):

I wish there were a better answer than this, but in the end I:

- uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2019 Community - problem persisted (no project would load, not even third party projects)
- repaired VS 2019 Community - problem persisted
- ran the [VS Install Cleanup Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), then reinstalled VS 2019 Community - problem persisted
- ran the Windows 8.1 SDK setup to validate that cleanup had not corrupted the SDK I installed around the time of my upgrade - problem persisted
- ran VS 2019 Community with the `/Log` option to see if I could understand what was happening: problem disappeared

Subsequently, running VS 2019 without the `/Log` option, everything is "back to normal". This makes no sense at all - recorded only for posterity.